# Can I turn a betty crocker angel cake mix into a normal sponge?

Tags: baking

I have a betty crocker angel food cake mix and we don't like the texture. Our usual box cake mix is the French vanilla which is super tasty and light and white. We love this mix.

My question is: can I substitute some of the water that is needed to make up the angel cake mix with and egg or two to make it more like a cake batter, as it's too much like meringue for us.

Comment: One of the problems with living on a sphere is that one person's night is another person's morning. Stack Exchange isn't designed for "I'm in a hurry" answers, I'm afraid.

Comment: Angel food cake basically *is* meringue (with a little bit of flour folded in)

Answer (score 4):

Angel food cake is a very different type of cake from a standard vanilla sponge cake it's mostly egg whites and sugar, other cakes have more flour, so if you want to try and modify it I'd be thinking more flour and maybe some butter.

If it was me I wouldn't bother though. It **may** be possible to modify the mix, but you'd have to reverse engineer the recipe from the box ingredients for both mixes, then work out the quantities to make one into the other. That is making big assumptions, and it's unlikely you'll get a good result without a lot of trial and error. It's a lot of work for little return when you can just go buy another box that you do like - enough work that you may as well make a cake from scratch rather than using a mix in the first place.